# Setup Certbot on xampp Apache Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, xampp, lets-encrypt, certbot

I tried to setup a SSL certificate with: https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-apache documentation.

It worked, the only problem was that it's on the wrong Apache server. I got 2 Apache server's on my Ubuntu 16.04 System. 1 is linking to /var/www/html and the other one (this one is of my XWAMPP server) is linking to /opt/lampp/htdocs

The Apache server that links to /var/www/html on this one the SSL is activated. With the command: `sudo certbot --apache`

I want it to be activated on the Apache server of the XAMPP. How can I edit this command so it calls the other Apache server?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this with next steps:
(*) First of all, you should be avaible certbot command and your virtualhost should be configured for the domain that you need https. f.e. mydomain.com. verify the domain is avaible in your browser.

1. sudo yum install certbot python2-certbot-apache
2. certbot --apache-ctl /opt/lampp/bin/apachectl

This, create the cert, in /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/.

3. Also, step 2 create a new vhost file in /opt/lampp/etc/extra/. please review.
4. then, add this new file in your vhost zone (/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf).
5. restart your xampp apache.

Answer (score 1):

It will work but for this you need and static ip and portforward 80 and 443 to your system ip and link with domain you can try no-ip they will give you free domain after that you need to visit https://www.sslforfree.com/
after this follow the step they say. After verifying you can download the ssl file. you need to put extract file in C:\xampp\apache\conf

after this goto C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra

and edit httpd-vhosts.conf and following thing you can change according to your domain or root directory

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@osticket.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/upload"
    ServerName osticketamcat.ddns.net
    ServerAlias osticketamcat.ddns.net
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCACertificateFile "C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl\ca_bundle.crt"
    SSLCertificateFile "C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.crt\server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.key\server.key"
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/upload">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score -2):

I solved this issue.

```
sudo certbot --apache-ctl /opt/lampp/bin/apachectl

sudo nano /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf
------------
# Virtual hosts
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts-le-ssl.conf #Add it here
```